# Returning from a goroutine which calls another goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I wonder what happens to goroutines called from another goroutine when it returns. Do they continue running or get terminated?
Here is a sample code to show what I mean:

```
func func() {
    // Doing something
}

func func2() {
        go func()
        // Doing things that end with a return
    }

func main() {
    go func2()
}
```

what happens to func() goroutine when func2() goroutine returns?

Comment: It keeps going. The runtime tracks them all independently.

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: I think he might have meant "returning _from_ a goroutine that call(ed) another goroutine".

Comment: thats cruel...why -4? It might be others question as well. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an experiment on excellent https://play.golang.org playground!
I recommend experiment there - it helps very much with golang studying.

https://play.golang.org/p/OJ9sgakV-S

I've added 2 second delay, because if program exit too quickly, you 'll not see results from goroutines.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: my problem maybe